Drools 7 => Businesscentral + Keycloak : Group permissions
I just setup a Docker stack with images of KIE server and Businesscentral at version 7.73 and a Keycloak 22 for auth management. The now deprecated KC adapter for Wildfly is also setup and I recreated users, roles and groups, so now I can login into Businesscentral with Keycloak.
Now that's done I would like to recreate the behavior of Businesscentral group permissions but in Keycloak (such as access to some spaces or projects). I didn't find any docs on this, is this possible ?
Thanks !

I resolved my issue by adding custom roles in the web.xml of business-central.war and creating those roles in Keycloak as well. Now I can handle permissions in the administration section of Businesscentral !
